# How to test for success when capturing an order using Paypal REST API SDK for PHP V2

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Im creating a Paypal integration using the REST API SDK for PHP V2 largely following the basic integration https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ but creating the payment and then capturing it using PHP and finally returning JSON back to the client.

All works fine, but when capturing using something like the following:

```
$capture_request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);

try {
    $client = new PayPalHttpClient($this->environment);
    $response = $client->execute($capture_request);
}
catch(HttpException $exception){

    // Return error to client
}

// Point X - How I do know its a success?
```

Once the $response has been returned how do I know payment was successful?

The sample code in the repo shows checking the response is a 201 at 'Point X' means 'Captured successfully' does that mean captured successfully, payment is a success all is good.... Or could there still be an issue with the payment that I need to alert the user to?

The PayPal docs here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/ talk about returning the response to the client and THEN checking for funding failure via 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED' in the Javascript

```
paypal.Buttons({
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    return fetch('CALL_MY_PHP_CODE', {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID
      })
    }).then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(details) {
      if (details.error === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
        return actions.restart();
      }
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

so if theres a funding failure, in the php does that return with a 201 also?

If I could test using the 'negative tests' I might be able to figure it out but I've had no success getting these working, and I'm not even sure they do work properly for the REST API.

I've tried generating errors using the Sandbox account with no funds etc and I don't get beyond the Create phase (which is fine) but I don't know what errors I need to be looking out for when Capturing the payment.

So my question is pretty much in the php what do I need at point 'X' in the code to be able to tell the client 'all is good move on' vs 'theres a problem do it again'.

Thanks